# How does `mbuffer -T` work?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I'm currently trying to make a tar backup to a tape with `mbuffer` acting as a buffer between e.g:

```
tar --acls -c /var/test | mbuffer -m 8G -P 100% -R 100M | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=256k
```

But the buffer is still empty about 10-20 times. So I wanted to use a file based buffer with the following command:

```
tar --acls -c /var/test | mbuffer -m 60G -T /srv/testbuffer -P 100% -R 100M | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=256k
```

My understanding was, that the option `-T` would create a file at the given location and use it as a read/write buffer.

But no file is created, and on one system `mbuffer` just hangs.

- Am I missing something?
- Does `mbuffer` create the file in a special way?
- Does `mbuffer` create the file in another directory?
- Does `mbuffer` extend/use the swap in some way?

As far as I read in the source of `mbuffer` (`settings.c`) `mbuffer` allocs space of the size of the `tmpfile` via `malloc()`.

Does that mean that I still need the same amount of RAM, or at least swap, as if I would use it without the `-T` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no file is created

`mbuffer -m 60G -T /srv/testbuffer` creates a file, opens it and unlinks it right after. If you check the file descriptors in `/proc/<PID of mbuffer>/fd` you will find one that points to

```
/srv/testbuffer (deleted)
```

This is quite a standard trick when it comes to temporary files. If `mbuffer` terminates for whatever reason (even if brutally killed), the filesystem will eventually free the space (in the worst case of power failure or kernel panic: after `fsck` in the future). There's no risk a totally unused, abandoned file will occupy your diskspace forever.

> on one system `mbuffer` just hangs

The tool actually reserves diskspace like `fallocate` (not just creates a sparse file like `truncate`) before it starts its main job of buffering data. Allocating a large file may take time. This delay depends on the filesystem type, possible fragmentation etc.

> Does that mean that I still need the same amount of RAM, or at least swap, as if I would use it without the `-T` parameter?

No. The file exists in the filesystem appropriate for the chosen path (`/srv/testbuffer` in your case), but the path no longer exists. (Note: a new file with the same path will be a separate file with different inode number).

Comment: Thanks, I also wrote to the maintainer of mbuffer and he gave me the same explanation. I was just about to Answer the question myself :)